# Using nested forEach loops to push to an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd love an explanation as to why the result of this else if statement doesn't match my expectation.
my if statement works fine, but else if statement pushes the same value to my array.
what I am trying to do is that, if by end of the period person is greater than 18 i want childEndDate to be dates of person date when he/she will become 18 years old.

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-53bmzz?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
this.childbirthYear.forEach(element => {
  if (periodEndYear - element < 18) {
    this.childEndDate = this.endDate;
  } else if (periodEndYear - element >= 18) {
    this.childBirthDate.forEach(year => {
      this.childEndDate = addYears(new Date(year), 18).toISOString();
    });
  }
  this.final.push(this.childEndDate);
});
console.log(this.final)
```

person dates i have now is:

```
this.childBirthDate = [
  '2012-02-16T20:00:00.000Z',
  '2010-05-19T20:00:00.000Z',
];
```

array returns

> ["2028-05-19T20:00:00.000Z", "2028-05-19T20:00:00.000Z"]

but it must return

> ["2030-05-19T20:00:00.000Z", "2028-05-19T20:00:00.000Z"]

Comment: 2 questions here,  1. What is addYears, 2. Why are you doing forEach again?

Comment: @Keith in answer to 1. `import addYears from 'date-fns/addYears';`

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: what is `periodEndYear` `this.childEndDate` `this.endDate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code should do for you...

```
    const greaterThan18s = this.childBirthDate
    .filter((birthDate: string) => (periodEndYear - new Date(birthDate).getFullYear()) >= 18)
    .forEach((birthDate: string) => this.olderThan18s.push(addYears(new Date(birthDate), 18).toISOString()));

    const lessThan18s = this.childBirthDate
    .filter(birthDate => periodEndYear - new Date(birthDate).getFullYear() < 18)
    .forEach((birthDate: string) => this.youngerThan18s.push(this.endDate));
```

And then arrange `olderThan18s` and `youngerThan18s` in a final array whatever way you like.

For example

```
this.final = [...olderThan18s, ...youngerThan18s]

// or

this.final = [...youngerThan18s, ...olderThan18s]
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer greaterThan18 works fine but when date is less than 18 it returns undefined. what am i doing wrong?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-c2g2ft?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Oh Ok!! Since I didn't follow the entire logic, I think I forgot to push to `final` in the case of `lessThan18s` filter. I have updated the answer, please take a look.

Comment: thanks again! if child is less than 18 value must be `this.endDate`. when i add less than 18 year it adds at at the begginning of array. [https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-c2g2ft?file=app/app.component.ts] here output must be: `["2030-02-16T20:00:00.000Z", "2028-05-19T20:00:00.000Z", "2031-11-08T11:03:47.396Z"]`

Comment: but it returns `["2031-11-08T11:03:47.396Z", "2030-02-16T20:00:00.000Z", "2028-05-19T20:00:00.000Z"]`

Comment: That is because we are processing and pushing `lessThan18s` before `greaterThan18s`. Move the `lessThan18s` after `greaterThan18s` and you should have your desired order of dates in the `final` array. Let me update the answer, and then you can take a look again.

Comment: @GalathyniusAelin Try now.. that I have updated the answer.

Comment: sry, but that solution doesn't work for me, because `this.childBirthDate` dates always will be in different order.

Comment: Then you can keep them in 2 separate arrays, one containing anything related to `olderThan18s` and one containing related to `youngerThans18s`. And then combine them whatever order you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `this.childEndDate` to hold the year when the person became 18 simply take the `element` which hold the birthyear and add with 18

dont know why you are using another forEach loop inside the else if

EDIT: in `new Date()` it expects `new Date(year, monthIndex)` hence the issue.

```
this.childbirthYear.forEach((element) => {
  if (periodEndYear - element < 18) {
    this.childEndDate = this.endDate;
  } else if (periodEndYear - element >= 18) {
    this.childEndDate = addYears(new Date(element, 1), 18).toISOString();
  }
  this.final.push(this.childEndDate);
});
console.log(this.final);
```

Gives output

```
["2030-01-31T18:30:00.000Z", "2028-01-31T18:30:00.000Z", "2031-11-09T16:09:40.621Z"]
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer! but it gives wrong output, what am i doing wrong? https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-eaxt8q?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: it returns 1988-01-01T00:00:02.012Z